Hello, I'm trying to communicate between 2 Raspberry pi pico boards, one master and one slave
master code:
#The master tries to take the temperature and humidity read with the help of a dht11 sensor from the slave
#The master tries to retrieve the temperature and humidity read with a dht11 sensor from the slave.
#As you can see, it manages to receive simple messages, but when the timer is enabled, 
#the master is stuck on the read function from

import machine
import utime
import dht

sdaPIN=machine.Pin(0)
sclPIN=machine.Pin(1)
led_rpi = machine.Pin("LED", machine.Pin.OUT)

i2c_master=machine.I2C(0,sda=sdaPIN, scl=sclPIN, freq=400000)
existDevice = False
infoData = False
dht_pin = machine.Pin(19)
sensor = dht.DHT11(dht_pin)
ht = "No new data found"

while True:
    devices = i2c_master.scan()
    if len(devices) != 0:
        existDevice = True
        led_rpi.high()
        if infoData == False:
            print('Number of I2C devices found=',len(devices))
            for device in devices:
                print("Device Hexadecimel Address= ",hex(device))
            infoData = True
            
        i2c_master.writeto(0x41,bytes([0xF0]))
        data = i2c_master.readfrom(0x41,16)
        print(data.decode())
        
        utime.sleep(2)
        
        i2c_master.writeto(0x41,bytes([0xF1]))
        data = i2c_master.readfrom(0x41,5)
        print(data.decode())
        
        utime.sleep(2)
        
        i2c_master.writeto(0x41,bytes([0xF2]))
        data = i2c_master.readfrom(0x41,5)
        print(data.decode())
        
        utime.sleep(2)
        
        i2c_master.writeto(0x41,bytes([0xF3]))
        data = i2c_master.readfrom(0x41,17)
        print(data.decode())
        
    else:
        existDevice = False
        led_rpi.low()
        print("No device found")
    utime.sleep(2)

slave code:
#The slave receives coded commands from the master, analyzes them and responds to the master depending on #what it received. For example, if it received the command 0xf3, it must send the data read by the dht3 #sensor.

#I implemented the collect_data function with a flag and a semaphore.

#Once every 10 seconds the global variable cd is updated and should be sent to the master.
#from machine import mem32,Pin,Timer

cd = "No new data found"
flagRW = 0
sem = False

#-------------------------------------------
#imported class for use pico as slave
class i2c_slave:
    I2C0_BASE = 0x40044000
    I2C1_BASE = 0x40048000
    IO_BANK0_BASE = 0x40014000
    
    mem_rw =  0x0000
    mem_xor = 0x1000
    mem_set = 0x2000
    mem_clr = 0x3000
    
    IC_CON = 0
    IC_TAR = 4
    IC_SAR = 8
    IC_DATA_CMD = 0x10
    IC_RAW_INTR_STAT = 0x34
    IC_RX_TL = 0x38
    IC_TX_TL = 0x3C
    IC_CLR_INTR = 0x40
    IC_CLR_RD_REQ = 0x50
    IC_CLR_TX_ABRT = 0x54
    IC_ENABLE = 0x6c
    IC_STATUS = 0x70
    
    def write_reg(self, reg, data, method=0):
        mem32[ self.i2c_base | method | reg] = data
        
    def set_reg(self, reg, data):
        self.write_reg(reg, data, method=self.mem_set)
        
    def clr_reg(self, reg, data):
        self.write_reg(reg, data, method=self.mem_clr)
                
    def __init__(self, i2cID = 0, sda=0,  scl=1, slaveAddress=0x41):
        self.scl = scl
        self.sda = sda
        self.slaveAddress = slaveAddress
        self.i2c_ID = i2cID
        if self.i2c_ID == 0:
            self.i2c_base = self.I2C0_BASE
        else:
            self.i2c_base = self.I2C1_BASE
        
        # 1 Disable DW_apb_i2c
        self.clr_reg(self.IC_ENABLE, 1)
        # 2 set slave address
        # clr bit 0 to 9
        # set slave address
        self.clr_reg(self.IC_SAR, 0x1ff)
        self.set_reg(self.IC_SAR, self.slaveAddress &0x1ff)
        # 3 write IC_CON  7 bit, enable in slave-only
        self.clr_reg(self.IC_CON, 0b01001001)
        # set SDA PIN
        mem32[ self.IO_BANK0_BASE | self.mem_clr |  ( 4 + 8 * self.sda) ] = 0x1f
        mem32[ self.IO_BANK0_BASE | self.mem_set |  ( 4 + 8 * self.sda) ] = 3
        # set SLA PIN
        mem32[ self.IO_BANK0_BASE | self.mem_clr |  ( 4 + 8 * self.scl) ] = 0x1f
        mem32[ self.IO_BANK0_BASE | self.mem_set |  ( 4 + 8 * self.scl) ] = 3
        # 4 enable i2c 
        self.set_reg(self.IC_ENABLE, 1)


    def any(self):
        # get IC_STATUS
        status = mem32[ self.i2c_base | self.IC_STATUS]
        # check RFNE receive fifio not empty
        if (status &  8) :
            return True
        return False
    
    def get(self):
        while not self.any():
            pass
        return mem32[ self.i2c_base | self.IC_DATA_CMD] & 0xff
    
    def anyRead(self):
        status = mem32[ self.i2c_base | self.IC_RAW_INTR_STAT] & 0x20
        if status :
            return True
        return False

    #read characters
    def put(self, data):
        # reset flag       
        self.clr_reg(self.IC_CLR_TX_ABRT, 1)
        status = mem32[ self.i2c_base | self.IC_CLR_RD_REQ]
        
        for char in data:
            # Wait for TX buffer to be not full
            while not (mem32[self.i2c_base | self.IC_STATUS] & (1 << 1)):
                pass
            mem32[self.i2c_base | self.IC_DATA_CMD] = ord(char) & 0xff
    
#-------------------------------------------
def colect_data(timer):
    global flagRW,sem,cd
    if not sem:
        temp = 0
        hum = 0
        for _ in range (10):
            sensor.measure()
            temp += sensor.temperature()
            hum += sensor.humidity()
        temp /= 10
        hum /= 10
        cd = "T:{:.2f}C/H:{:.2f}%".format(temp,hum)
        print(cd)
        flagRW = 1
        sem = True            
            
dataTimer = Timer()
dataTimer.init(period=10000, mode=Timer.PERIODIC, callback=colect_data)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import utime
    import dht
    from machine import Pin
    from machine import mem32
    led_rpi = Pin(25,Pin.OUT)
    dht_pin = machine.Pin(19)
    sensor = dht.DHT11(dht_pin)
        
    s_i2c = i2c_slave(0,sda=0,scl=1,slaveAddress=0x41)
      
    while True:

        command = 0
        if s_i2c.any():
            command = s_i2c.get()
            print("Comanda primita de la master : {}".format(hex(command)))
        if command == 0xf0:
            print("Hello from master!")
            if s_i2c.anyRead():
                s_i2c.put("Hello from slave")
        elif command == 0xf1:
            if s_i2c.anyRead():
                s_i2c.put("#####")
        elif command == 0xf2:
            #utime.sleep(5)
            print(cd)
            if s_i2c.anyRead():
                s_i2c.put("*****")
        elif command == 0xf3:
            if flagRW == 1:
                if sem:
                    if s_i2c.anyRead():
                        s_i2c.put(cd)
                    flagRW = 0
                    sem = False
                    print("Trimis")
            else:
                cd = "No new data found"
                if s_i2c.anyRead():
                    s_i2c.put(cd)

The slave receives coded commands from the master, analyzes them and responds to the master depending on what it received. For example, if it received the command 0xf3, it must send the data read by the dht3 sensor.
I implemented the collect_data function with a flag and a semaphore.
Once every 10 seconds the global variable cd is updated and should be sent to the master.
However I get error
I understood that it is quite difficult to use raspberry pi pico as a slave, so I used the i2c_slave class found on their forum.
However, when I try to send simple messages, it works, but when functions are called or a delay is introduced in the slave, the master stops responding. I implemented the data collection function using a timer, but I still have the same problem. Can you please help me with a solution?

What kind of errors are you getting? Fatal errors? Freezing of code execution? Also can you tell how are they both communicating? using PIOs or Wifi (pico_w board supports this)? You may want to include RPC type of system.

I get the following error
OSError: [Errno 110] ETIMEDOUT
I use a pico w as master and a simple pico as slave

It looks like it is a communication time-out error, make sure the communication between master and slave board is well established.
